# How to test filterBooks function in this component?? (React - Jest - Enzyme )

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

**My Component:**

```
const Books = ({books, searchField}) => {
 
 const filterBooks = () => {
   return books.filter(b => b.name.includes(searchField)) 
 }

 return (
    <BookList books={filterBooks()}/>
 )
}
```

**BookList Component:**

```
const BookList = ({books}) => {
  return (
     books.map(b => {
        return<BookCard book={b}/>
     })
  )
}
```

**BookCard Component**:

```
const BookCard =(book) => {
  return( 
        <div>
           <h2>{book.name}</h2>
           <p>{book.price}</p>
         </div>
   )

}
```

I need to test **filterBooks** function, but since i am using functional component i can't use `instance()` method since it returns `null` in functional components

in Class component i can do that which i can't achieve in functional components:

```
let wrapper;

beforeEach(() => {
 let mockProps = {
     books: [],
     searchField: ''
 }
  wrapper = shallow(<Books/>);
})

 it('filter Books correctly', () => {
   mockProps = {
     books: [
      {
         name: 'ants',
         price: '$10'
      },
      {
        name: 'the secret',
         price: '$10'
      } 
    ],
     searchField: 'a'
   }

    wrapper = shallow(<Books {...mockProps}/>)
    expect(wrapper.instance().filterBooks().toEqual([{name: 'ants', price: '$10'}])
 })
```

How can i achieve that in my functional component??

Comment: Test it via the expected *behaviour*: render (not just shallowly) the component with an array of books, and check that the right ones get filtered out based on the search field by seeing what elements are rendered.

Comment: @jonrsharpe
Yes this what i want to achieve but i couldn't, i thought to use mount instead of shallow, and then find books filtered by name, i couldn't do that, since i can have many books rendered there, how can i test that some books exists while others not??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [.find(selector) => ShallowWrapper](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/find.html) to find the `BookList` component shallow wrapper and check its `books` prop.

E.g.

`Books.js`:

```js
import React from 'react';
import BookList from './BookList';

const Books = ({ books, searchField }) => {
  const filterBooks = () => {
    return books.filter((b) => b.name.includes(searchField));
  };

  return <BookList books={filterBooks()} />;
};

export default Books;
```

`BookList.js`:

```js
import React from 'react';
import BookCard from './BookCard';

const BookList = ({ books }) => {
  return books.map((b) => {
    return <BookCard book={b} />;
  });
};

export default BookList;
```

`Books.test.js`:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import Books from './Books';
import BookList from './BookList';

describe('66074394', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    const mockProps = {
      books: [
        {
          name: 'ants',
          price: '$10',
        },
        {
          name: 'the secret',
          price: '$10',
        },
      ],
      searchField: 'a',
    };

    const wrapper = shallow(<Books {...mockProps} />);
    expect(wrapper.find(BookList).prop('books')).toEqual([{ name: 'ants', price: '$10' }]);
  });
});
```

unit test result:

```
 PASS  examples/66074394/Books.test.js
  66074394
    ✓ should pass (6 ms)

-------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File         | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files    |   83.33 |      100 |      50 |   82.35 |                   
 BookCard.js |      75 |      100 |       0 |      75 | 4                 
 BookList.js |   66.67 |      100 |       0 |   66.67 | 5-6               
 Books.js    |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
-------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3.57 s
```